# How to properly integrate MobilePush with Objective-C?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce-sdk-android, react-native

I have an integration of MobilePush on my project (React-Native), but with the recent updates i had to update to the latest version of the SDK (8.0.4). But i getting some issues with it.

For example, in iOS i have successfully imported the modules via Swift Package Manager, and all the integration stuff on the guide, but there is no `ConfigBuilder`, in any of the imported packages like in the example code:

```
SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: configuration).build())

{ ... }

SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder()
     .setPush(
          config: configuration,
          onCompletion: {result in print("TODO, Module initialization result is: \(result.rawValue)")}
     ).build())
```

as showed in the example the `PushConfigBuilder` is filled with the informations and passed to `config` in `ConfigBuilder` and then passed to `initializeSdk` method, but the `initializeSdk` accepts an instance of `SFMCSdkConfig` witch is incompatible with the `ConfigBuilder` type (because i cant import or use him).

With this context, how i can set the config (`PushConfigBuilder`) and integrate with the `SFMCSdk`? **I'm using `Objective-C` in iOS and `Java` for Android**, and i have tried to find something in the docs or the LearningApp in these languages, but i didn't find anything.

Currently following this guides:

Android: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/

iOS: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/

Answer (score 1):

8.x versions are not currently supported (20220131) with the SDK's ReactNative plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i'm not using the SDK's ReactNative plugin. I manually integrated the plugin.

Comment: May the force be with you.